# Are you able to add code for other text buttons with a local script inside somewhere else in Luau?

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

So im making a cookie clicker made with gui in Luau and im trying to make it so when you click a button it takes cookies away and adds a multiplyer, but the script is inside the cookie button

```
local cookies = 0
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local clickMultiplyer = 1

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    cookies = cookies + cm
    plr.PlayerGui.CookiesDisplayText.Text = cookies
end

--This first part works just fine--

plr.PlayerGui.ShopUi.BuyButton:Connect(function()
    if cookies == 100 or cookies =< 100 then
        cookies = cookies - 100
        cm = cm + 1
    else
        plr.PlayerGui.ShopUi.BuyButton.Text = "not enough cash"
        wait(.5)
        plr.PlayerGui.ShopUi.BuyButton.Text = "Buy cost:100 +1 clickmultiplyer"
    end
end
```

Theres no errors but it simply does not work, thank you in advance :))

I fixed all errors that vs code and roblox detected.

Comment: what is `BuyButton`? Is it a TextButton or ImageButton?

Comment: The buybutton is just my name i set for a textbutton

Answer (score 0):

It's spelled "multiplier".  You have two variables for the same thing.  This should work, assuming everything else is set up properly.

```
local cookies = 0
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local multiplier = 1

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    cookies += multiplier
    -- This may cause issues, a TextLabel inside of PlayerGui should not be visible unless it's parented to a ScreenGui
    plr.PlayerGui.CookiesDisplayText.Text = cookies
end

plr.PlayerGui.ShopUi.BuyButton:Connect(function()
    if cookies >= 100 then
        cookies -= 100
        cm += 1
    else
        plr.PlayerGui.ShopUi.BuyButton.Text = "not enough cash"
        task.wait(.5)
        plr.PlayerGui.ShopUi.BuyButton.Text = "Buy cost:100 +1 clickmultiplier"
    end
end
```

Comment: The `BuyButton` TextButton needs to connect to the `Activated` signal as well. `plr.PlayerGui.ShopUi.BuyButton.Activated:Connect(function()`. That's probably why nothing was happening when they clicked the button.

Comment: OMG thank you i have no clue how i missed this lol

Comment: @Kylaaa Damn, I knew something looked wrong with that, lol.  I haven't done anything with Roblox in 6 months or so, I'm a little rusty.